# How to connect multiple classes to build a single array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple files, each its own PHP Class, and inside some functions, in these classes, I call a function inside another class that I set up to build an array. To visualize this, I have

```
Class 1 - Runs I15_Helper::buildlog('Some text');
Class 2 - Runs I15_Helper::buildlog('Some other text');
Class 3 - Runs I15_Helper::buildlog('Some more text');
```

Class I15_Helper - has a function called buildlog used to create an array of text passed to it.

The solution to this could be obvious and I am just not seeing it. Below is the function I have tried to use to build the array. I assume I could do this by storing the array in a session but I am hoping there is a better way to handle this.

```
public static function buildlog($text, $submitlog = false) {
if(!is_array($log_array)) {
        $log_array = array();
}

if($text != "") {
        array_push($log_array, $text);
}

    if($submitlog) {
        log($log_array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to create an array of texts passed in function `Runs I15_Helper::buildlog` ?

Comment: If all calls are going to add items to the same log (array), then just have the array as a static property in your `I15_Helper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a `static array` will help you in getting desired output.
Defining a simple `array` will not help because after that you won't be able to refer to that array with `$this` as you are invoking static function `buildlog` and so there is `no object is in current context`.

```
class I15_Helper
{
    public static $logArray=array();
    public static function buildlog($text, $submitlog = false)
    {
        if ($text != "")
        {
            array_push(self::$logArray, $text);
        }

        if ($submitlog)
        {
            log($log_array);
        }
    }

}
I15_Helper::buildlog("sa");
I15_Helper::buildlog("sasa");
I15_Helper::buildlog("sasasa");
print_r(I15_Helper::$logArray);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => sa
    [1] => sasa
    [2] => sasasa
)
```